# Change system text in videoview - "Cannot play video", "Sorry, this video cannot be played"

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-videoview

is there any way to change default text of error when video cannot be played?

[image]

I am using Android 1.5 and want to change it when it's set on Chinese language - I want Chinese `AlertDialog` to be in Slovak - because in Android 1.5 there is no `Locale.Slovak` so I have to "fake it" and make my own system text in dialogs.
Thank You :)

Comment: Can I ask the obvious question of why Android 1.5?  Its ancient, almost nothing was released on it, and it doesn't have a feature you need.  If you're selling the app, I'd say ignore versions that old.  If its in house, buy new hardware or use a newer OS image.

Comment: Yes I know it's very old. But my bachelor project is for system that is based on just 1.5. It's for buses, it look like this: http://goo.gl/4Qvd8  so I cannot make it on any other system :( So It cannot be changed at all? :(